# selected option is not hitting to database using magento

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1" <?php echo($data["optradio"]== 1 ?'checked="checked"':''); ?> />
                            Male </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2" <?php echo($data["optradio"]== 2 ? 'checked="checked"':''); ?> />
                            Female </label>
```

I want to store the selected value of gender in database. The code i have written as shown above.
Please guide me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Where is the code to insert into DB?

Comment: if($data)
        {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerSessionID);
            $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
            $customer->addData($data);
            $customer->save();
            $session->addSuccess("Form successfully saved.");
            $this->_redirectReferer();
        }

Comment: in controller,i have written this code

Comment: show your complete function.....will be better if you update it on the question